# Move uncomitted changes from master to branch

Tags: git

I have started making some changes recently to my master branch to add featureX. I have created 1 new file and edited 6 others. I have not committed any of the changes. For the time being, I would like to work on featureX on a separate branch and leave the master untouched until I am sure featureX works correctly.

I know I should have started a new branch before I started making these changes for featureX, but is there anyway to get the uncommitted changes I've made to the master branch into a featureX branch and restore the master to its pre featureX state?

Comment: You can actually switch branches and commit those changes to that branch, then go back to master. Otherwise, you can do `git stash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new branch (`git checkout -b your_new_feature`) should do the job - otherwise, you could try this:

```
git stash
git checkout -b your_new_feature
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to `stash` away the changes, then apply it somewhere else:

```
git stash
git checkout -b other_branch
git stash apply
```

Read more on `git stash` [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html).

---

As I *just* learned (and tried), you can actually just checkout to your branch and git will remember what files were changed. So

```
git checkout -b other_branch
```

should be enough.

---

A note: It is important to also learn `git stash`. In this case, there is no problem. However, if the `other_branch` already exists, it may have its own changes and therefore there could be merge conflicts. In that case simply writing

```
git checkout other_branch
```

may fail with a message like this:

> error: You have local changes to 'whatever'; cannot switch branches.

In such a case, you should use the method above and after `git stash apply`, resolve the possible conflicts.

Comment: It's not needed, see birryree comment